# Firebase realtime database doesn't update database when i sign up

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send information to the firebase database, I am connected and already checked multiple times and i can't find the error here's my code

**Here's the database reference command** 
everything is well put together and working, i don't exactly know why it doesn't really allow me to send information doesn't show any errors and everything

```
  userInformation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Users");

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

  private void saveUserInformation(){
  String UserName = NameET.getText().toString();
    String Userbirthday = dateBirth.toString();
    String Userdate_drivinglicense = dateLicense.toString();
    String UserCountry = Countries.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String UserGender = Genders.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String HouseLocationLat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    String HouseLocationLong = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

    Userinformation userInfo = new Userinformation(UserName,Userbirthday,Userdate_drivinglicense,UserCountry,UserGender,HouseLocationLat,HouseLocationLong);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        userInformation.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInfo);
    }

    Toast.makeText(UserInformationActivity.this, "Saving Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, i'm connected to the database and it worked out many times but after i implemented the location.getlatitude and longitude, it seemed to not send any information, I've made a constructor in a outsider class

Comment: Add a [completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) on your `userInformation.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInfo);` and check for any errors.

Comment: In which place are you calling this method `saveUserInformation()`?

Comment: I'm calling this method on a button that has a onclicklistener,

Comment: @AndréKool i'm not looking for something to tell me if it works or not, i want the information to be saved in the database, the toast works meaning that the method works but i don't see any information updates in the firebase database

Comment: @captindfru The toast only shows that the line of code before it ran, not that the write to the database (which happens asynchronously) was successful. Only a completion listener will tell you if the Firebase client thinks the write was successful, which is key to troubleshooting in this phase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you give me an example, i'm not a pro coder and i can't recognize what you mean by completion listener, i searched but i can't understand an example of it

Comment: See this example in the legacy Firebase docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback

Comment: Update: I added an OncompleteListener and it worked successfully but i don't see anything in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue i had was that i didn't implent an Getter and Setter in my Java Class which is connected to the UserInformation, and i had to create a new child in the database with the name "Users" since it wasn't created automatically as it should be, also changed the names of variables in my

`Userinformation userInfo = new Userinformation(UserName,Userbirthday,Userdate_drivinglicense,UserCountry,UserGender,HouseLocationLat,HouseLocationLong);`

So it can connect to the database correctly Thanks for all the help :)